# Finding new position of a point in $\Bbb R^2$ after rotating it about a vector in $\Bbb R^2$.

Tags: analytic-geometry, rotations

> > Suppose $(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$. Suppose we rotate this point about a vector $(a,b) \in \Bbb R^2$ through an angle $\theta$. Find the coordinate of the new point.

What I have done is as follows $:$

I first translate the vector $(a,b)$ suitably so that it becomes the origin in the new coordinate system. Let $(x',y')$ be the new coordinate of $(x,y)$. Then $x'=x-a$ and $y'=y-b$.  Now in order to find out the coordinate of the point $(x,y)$ after rotating it about the vector $(a,b)$ through an angle $\theta$ we need to rotate $(x',y')$ about the origin in the new coordinate system through the same angle $\theta$. After rotating let the coordinate of $(x',y')$ be changed to $(x'',y'')$ in the new coordinate system. Then $x'' = x' \cos \theta - y' \sin \theta$ and $y'' = x' \sin \theta + y' \cos \theta$. Replacing $x'$ and $y'$ by $x-a$ and $y-b$ respectively we get the coordinate of $(x'',y'')$ in the old coordinate system which is the required coordinate of $(x,y)$ after rotating it about the vector $(a,b)$ through an angle $\theta$. So

$$x'' = (x-a) \cos \theta -(y-b) \sin \theta.$$

$$y'' = (x-a) \sin \theta + (y-b) \cos \theta.$$

is the required coordinate of the new point. But the answer given in my book is not matching with the above one. It is given as

$$x'' = (x-a) \cos \theta - (y-b) \sin \theta + a.$$
$$y'' = (x-a) \sin \theta + (y-b) \cos \theta + b.$$

Where have I done mistake? Please help me in this regard.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carefully note that $(x'',y'')$ are co-ordinates of the required point with respect to the translated axis, the new co-ordinate system $(x',y')$. To get the co-ordinates of the point $(p,q)$ in the original co-ordinate system, we have $x''=p-a\implies p=x''+a;y''=q-b\implies q=y''+b$.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Shubham Johri. I messed up with all those primes. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I observe another thing from here that rotations and translation do not commute with each other. What I have done here is translation followed by rotation. If I do the same thing in the reverse direction i.e. first rotation and then translation I would have ended up with the coordinate $(x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta + a, x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta + b)$. Isn't it so? Which actually proves in the group theoritic context that the group $G$ of rigid motoins in a plane is not  commutative. In particular the subgroup $H \subset G$ of all orientation preserving rigid motoins is not commutative.

Comment: While I'm not really sure about Group Theory, you are correct about the former. Although, here, the question meant specifically for the rotation to happen about $(a,b)$, and it wouldn't make much sense to rotate about $(0,0)$

Comment: Ok. It's fine. What is your background @Shubham Johri? Your name suggests that you are an Indian national like me.

Comment: Yes, I'm an Indian undergraduate in Applied Mathematics.